# Request: Need a Query that will return the Run Steps and Step Status of the last executed Test Lab run

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

Hello helpful HP ALM gurus,

I currently use the following query:

```
SELECT
CF_ITEM_NAME as "Test Set Folder Name",
CY_CYCLE as "Test Set Name",
TS_NAME as "Test Case Name",
RN_STATUS as "Test Case Status",
ST_STEP_NAME as "Test Step Name",
ST_STATUS as "Test Step Status",
ST_DESCRIPTION as "Test Step Description",
ST_EXPECTED as "Test Step Expected Result",
ST_ACTUAL as "Test Step Actual Result",
RN_HOST as "Test Host Name",
RN_TESTER_NAME as "Tester Name",
ST_EXECUTION_DATE as "Test Step Execution Date",
ST_EXECUTION_TIME as "Test Step Execution Time"
FROM STEP a, TEST b, CYCLE c,RUN d,CYCL_FOLD e
where
a.ST_TEST_ID=b.TS_TEST_ID and
c.CY_CYCLE_ID=d.RN_CYCLE_ID and
d.RN_TEST_ID=b.TS_TEST_ID and
e.CF_ITEM_ID=c.CY_FOLDER_ID and
RN_HOST IS NOT NULL and
RN_TESTER_NAME IS NOT NULL and
CF_ITEM_PATH like 'AAAAAG%'
//CF_ITEM_ID like '267%' //Comment this or CF_ITEM_PATH and use the other
ORDER BY TS_NAME,RN_RUN_ID,ST_RUN_ID,ST_EXECUTION_DATE,ST_EXECUTION_TIME ASC
```

Unfortunately, the problem with this query is that it requires me to run a separate query that captures all the CF_ITEM_PATH values in my multi-item ALM Project. I then have to plug in that string into the "CF_ITEM_PATH like" field and get a list.

Is it possible to create and run a query that returns at least the following data? TS_NAME, ST_STEP_NAME, ST_STATUS_ST_DESCRIPTION, ST_EXPECTED, ST_ACTUAL, ST_EXECUTION_DATE

I would like the query to pull up this data for the most recent / last executed Test Set in Test Plan. Is this possible? How can it be done? If it cannot be done, can I change my above query to use the Run ID value of a Test Set instead of the CF_ITEM_PATH to obtain the information I desire? How?

Please note that I am not experienced with SQL and would require detailed instructions.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C1.CY_CYCLE_ID , C1.CY_CYCLE AS TEST_SET_NAME , TC1.TC_TEST_ID , T.TS_NAME
, R1.RN_STATUS , R1.RN_RUN_ID , R1.RN_RUN_NAME, R1.RN_TESTER_NAME ,S1.ST_STEP_NAME , S1.ST_DESCRIPTION , S1.ST_EXPECTED , S1.ST_ACTUAL
FROM CYCL_FOLD CF1 , CYCL_FOLD  CF2 , CYCLE C1 , TESTCYCL TC1 , TEST T , RUN R1 , STEP S1
WHERE
CF1.CF_ITEM_NAME = 'Cycle One' AND
CF2.CF_ITEM_PATH LIKE CONCAT(CF1.CF_ITEM_PATH,'%') AND
C1.CY_FOLDER_ID = CF2.CF_ITEM_ID AND
TC1.TC_CYCLE_ID = C1.CY_CYCLE_ID
AND
T.TS_TEST_ID = TC1.TC_TEST_ID
AND
R1.RN_TESTCYCL_ID = TC1.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
AND
 R1.RN_TEST_ID = TC1.TC_TEST_ID
AND
 S1.ST_RUN_ID = R1.RN_RUN_ID
```

Comment: Hello @Barney. Thank you for your time and assistance. This script returns an error when executed, as follows:  `ERROR -----------------------------------------------------  
The SQL query <Query1> has failed to run, with the following error:  
[Mercury][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`